# Django Can't Find a static file that's already there

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm facing a very peculiar problem using Django. So basically I have a CSS static file inside <static/css> directory, and here's the strange message from terminal:  "GET /home/.../django/mysite/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1932, while the file is actually there!

settings file:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
STATIC_URL = str(BASE_DIR) + '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))
STATICFILES_DIR = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
```

I have used the command "python manage.py collectstatic", but it didn't work; I also checked out this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/ but there was no solution for me... Please tell me what's wrong!

Comment: The problem is that you're treating `STATIC_URL` as a _directory_.  The actual css file is in the directory `/home/.../django/mysite/static/css/style.css`, but that is not a url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making your [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url) as follows

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

You are currently constructing it out of your project directory structure, but the web page needs it in a website context, eg, domain.com/static/

Comment: Thank you so much! Somehow it worked! So this is before "python manage.py collectstatic" or after, or maybe it doesn't matter?!..

Comment: Collectstatic is generally done in production environments, eg, where DEBUG = False.  This puts all your various static directories in one place, STATIC_ROOT, for easier handling by whatever means you are going to use to handle images.  While DEBUG= TRUE django will handle it for you by looking through the various static directories in apps and STATIC_DIRS etc, but this isn't ideal for a live site - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/deployment/